Handbrake: Is it useful to use Fast 480p30 for 480 mkv videos, or can I stick with Fast 1080p30?
I'm fairly new to using Handbrake, and the numerous configurations are a bit confusing.
I've looked in the documentation and on the forums, and I've done some tests myself, and noticed that with Fast 1080p30, the size of mkv 480p videos is often reduced to 30%.
If I understand correctly, the resolution of the configuration only affects the resolution limit, so should I bother checking all the resolutions of my videos and use the correct configuration instead (e.g. Fast 480p30 for 480p videos, Fast 720p30 for 720 videos, etc.), or can I use Fast 1080p30 for everything, while maintaining a reasonable level of compression?
Note that I'm not looking to know if Very Fast/Fast/HQ/etc. is better, as Fast seems to be a good compromise and I'm not really limited by the space available on my computer.

There's no point in reencoding to a higher resolution than the original.

@ChanganAuto : that's not what I want and I never said that. Using the preset 'Fast 1080p30' on a 480p video doesn't change its resolution.

If you compare the profiles, there’s one decisive difference: Fast 1080p30 uses a Constant Rate Factor (CRF) of 22 while Fast 480p30 uses a CRF of 20, which results in higher quality but also larger files. (Furthermore, with Fast 480p30, the encoder is restricted to Main Profile Level 3.1, but that shouldn’t matter.)
You can of course use Fast 1080p30 if you are satisfied with the quality.

Thanks @Daniel B. I actually don't see any difference with the originals, whatever their resolution is.
